# Changing Section Numbering Ruins TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, section-titles

I am trying to include the word "Appendix" in the section titles before the appendix number. Trying `\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}:}` works, but messes up the table of contents - the section name is printed over the section number:
[image: Image of issue]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Intro}
    content

    \appendix
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}:}

    \section{Test 1}
    content

    \section{Test 2}
    content

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the `appendix` package and use the `appendices` environment`. There are two ways to do that, and also other goodies for the table of contents and the header. See the  documentation, pp.3-4 for details.